# Can we eliminate inverses in the middle of a matrix product? $ABX^{-1}XCD = ABCD$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

If $A = S\Lambda S^{-1}$ where $\Lambda$ is a diagonal matrix of eigenvalues of $A$.

Then for the proof of $A^{2} = S\Lambda^{2}S^{-1}$, I was thinking:
$$A^{2} = (S\Lambda S^{-1})(S\Lambda S^{-1}) = S\Lambda S^{-1}S\Lambda S^{-1} = S\Lambda I\Lambda S^{-1} = S\Lambda \Lambda S^{-1} = S\Lambda^{2}S^{-1}$$

Matrix multiplication doesn't commute so how can we eliminate those middle matrices? Or can we not do that usually and this is just some weird edge case where it works.

Does it generally hold that: $ABX^{-1}XCD = ABCD$?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes! In general, if $A=S\Lambda S^{-1}$ then we have $$A^{n}=S\Lambda^{n}S^{-1}$$ for $n\in\mathbb{Z}_{>0}$. This follows from the fact that we can write $$A^n=\underbrace{(S\Lambda S^{-1})(S\Lambda S^{-1})\cdots (S\Lambda S^{-1})}_{n}$$ and then by associativity of matrices we have $$A^n=S\Lambda (S^{-1}S)\Lambda (S^{-1} S)\cdots (S^{-1}S)\Lambda S^{-1}$$ Hence we see that all the $S^{-1}S=\text{id} $ cancel out so we end up with $$A^n=S\Lambda (S^{-1}S)\Lambda (S^{-1} S)\cdots (S^{-1}S)\Lambda S^{-1}=S\underbrace{\Lambda\cdots\Lambda}_{n}S^{-1}=S\Lambda^{n}S^{-1}$$

I think you confused associativity with commutativity. Simply put, commutativity means that for 2 matrices $A,B$ we have $AB=BA$ (which in general isn't the case for matrices other than the identity matrix which commutes with all matrices). Associativity on the other hand, means that for matrices $A,B,C$ we have $(AB)C=A(BC)$ which does in fact hold for matrix multiplication. So in this case you're applying the associative property rather than the commutative property.

Comment: Oh yes I definitely confused the two! Thank you so much!